# R: fastest way to extract all substrings contained between two substrings

Tags: regex, r, string, substring

I am on the lookout for an efficient way to extract all matches between two substrings in a character string. E.g. say I want to extract all substrings contained between string

```
start="strt"
```

and

```
stop="stp"
in string
x="strt111stpblablastrt222stp"
```

I would like to get vector

```
"111" "222"
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in R? Using a regular expression perhaps? Or are there better ways?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For something simple like this, base R handles this just fine.

You can switch on [**PCRE**](http://www.pcre.org/) by using `perl=T` and use [**lookaround**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookaround) assertions.

```
x <- 'strt111stpblablastrt222stp'
regmatches(x, gregexpr('(?<=strt).*?(?=stp)', x, perl=T))[[1]]
# [1] "111" "222"
```

**Explanation**:

```
(?<=          # look behind to see if there is:
  strt        #   'strt'
)             # end of look-behind
.*?           # any character except \n (0 or more times)
(?=           # look ahead to see if there is:
  stp         #   'stp'
)             # end of look-ahead
```

**EDIT:** Updated below answers according to the new syntax.

You may also consider using the **stringi** package.

```
library(stringi)
x <- 'strt111stpblablastrt222stp'
stri_extract_all_regex(x, '(?<=strt).*?(?=stp)')[[1]]
# [1] "111" "222"
```

And `rm_between` from the **qdapRegex** package.

```
library(qdapRegex)
x <- 'strt111stpblablastrt222stp'
rm_between(x, 'strt', 'stp', extract=TRUE)[[1]]
# [1] "111" "222"
```

Comment: +1, for completion I'll mention that `strt\K` could replace the `(?<=strt)` (nothing wrong with it, just another option)

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about speed in R strings there is only one package to do this - [`stringi`](http://stringi.rexamine.com)

```
 x <- "strt111stpblablastrt222stp"
 hwnd <- function(x1) regmatches(x1,gregexpr('(?<=strt).*?(?=stp)',x1,perl=T))
 Tim <- function(x1) regmatches(x1, gregexpr("(?<=strt)(?:(?!stp).)*", x1, perl=TRUE))
 stringr <- function(x1) str_extract_all(x1, perl('(?<=strt).*?(?=stp)'))
 akrun <- function(x1) genXtract(x1, "strt", "stp")
 stringi <- function(x1) stri_extract_all_regex(x1, perl('(?<=strt).*?(?=stp)'))

 require(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(stringi(x), hwnd(x), Tim(x), stringr(x))
Unit: microseconds
       expr     min       lq  median       uq     max neval
 stringi(x)  46.778  58.1030  64.017  67.3485 123.398   100
    hwnd(x)  61.498  73.1095  79.084  85.5190 111.757   100
     Tim(x)  60.243  74.6830  80.755  86.3370 102.678   100
 stringr(x) 236.081 261.9425 272.115 279.6750 440.036   100
```

Unfortunately I couldn't test @akrun solution because qdap package has some errors during installation. And only his solution looks like the one that can beat stringi...

Comment: I would expect `genXtract` to be much slower (as much as 10-20 times slower).  It's built for flexibility and ease of use.  In many cases a researcher's time is more valuable than computational time.  If that's the case `genXtract` is an excellent choice.  If you are after speed then I, like you, am a huge fan of `stringi`.

Comment: I am more than just `stringi` fan - I'm an author :)

Comment: `perl is deprecated, use regex instead`, I prefered not to edit the answer as the benchmark results might have changed since then.

Answer (score 5):

You may also consider:

```
library(qdap)
unname(genXtract(x, "strt", "stp"))
#[1] "111" "222"
```

Speed comparison

```
 x1 <- rep(x,1e5)
 system.time(res1 <- regmatches(x1,gregexpr('(?<=strt).*?(?=stp)',x1,perl=T)))
 #   user  system elapsed 
 #  2.187   0.000   2.015 

 system.time(res2 <- regmatches(x1, gregexpr("(?<=strt)(?:(?!stp).)*", x1, perl=TRUE)))
 #user  system elapsed 
 #  1.902   0.000   1.780 

 system.time(res3 <- str_extract_all(x1, perl('(?<=strt).*?(?=stp)')))
 # user  system elapsed 
 #  6.990   0.000   6.636 

 system.time(res4 <- genXtract(x1, "strt", "stp")) ##setNames(genXtract(...), NULL) is a bit slower
 # user  system elapsed 
 # 1.457   0.000   1.414 

 names(res4) <- NULL
identical(res1,res4)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thx for the additional slightly faster option - that's nice!!

Answer (score 2):

Since there can be several start/stop strings per input, I think a regex will be the most efficient solution:

```
(?<=strt)(?:(?!stp).)*
```

will match everything after `strt` until the end of the string or `stp`, whichever comes first. If you want to assert that there always is a `stp`, add `(?=stp)` at the end of the regex. You can even apply this regex to a vector.

```
regmatches(subject, gregexpr("(?<=strt)(?:(?!stp).)*", subject, perl=TRUE));
```