# Extract data between rows r

Tags: r

I have the following row:

```
rep(c("foo",rep(c('A','B'),2),"bar",rep(c("C","D"),2)),2)

 [1] "foo" "A"   "B"   "A"   "B"   "bar" "C"   "D"   "C"   "D"   "foo" "A"  
[13] "B"   "A"   "B"   "bar" "C"   "D"   "C"   "D"
```

I would like to extract the data between 'foo' and  and 'bar' to get

```
[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

How would you do perform this task in r?

Comment: Do `foo` and `bar` alternate (i.e. `foo,...bar,...,foo,...`) in the vector that you are really working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this approach which I think is the easiest to understand and a more R idiomatic way of doing it.

```
s <- rep(c("foo", rep(c('A','B'), 2), "bar", rep(c("C","D"), 2)), 2) # Your vector

get <- c(mapply(seq, which(s == "foo") + 1, which(s == "bar") - 1))
s[get]
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

Answer (score 3):

May be this helps:
If `vec` is the vector

```
vec[mapply(`:`, grep("foo", vec), grep("bar", vec))[-c(1,6),]]
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

or

```
vec1 <- vec[mapply(`:`, grep("foo", vec), grep("bar", vec))]
vec1[!grepl(paste(c("foo","bar"),collapse="|"), vec1)]
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

#### Update

For a vector like below:

```
  vec1 <- c("foo", "A", "B", "bar", "C", "D", "bar", "foo", "A", "B", "A",
 "bar", "C", "D", "D", "zoo", "A", "B", "foo", "A", "bar", "B", "A", "zoo",
 "A", "foo", "A", "B")
```

you could use:

```
fun1 <- function(vec, first, second) {
lst <- split(vec, cumsum(vec == first))
unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) {
    indx <- match(second, x) - 1
    if (!is.na(indx) & indx>1) {
        x[2:indx]
    }
 }), use.names = F)

}

 fun1(vec1, "foo", "bar")
 #[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "A"
 
 fun1(vec, "foo", "bar")
 #[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

BTW, @David Arenburg's method works for both cases.

Answer (score 3):

Using similar methodology to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773737/r-fastest-way-to-extract-all-substrings-contained-between-two-substrings/24773915#24773915)

```
temp <- paste(rep(c("foo",rep(c('A','B'),2),"bar",rep(c("C","D"),2)),2), collapse = "")
unlist(strsplit(regmatches(temp, gregexpr('(?<=foo).*?(?=bar)', temp, perl=T))[[1]], ""))
##[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `foo` is first among the two and that they alternate:

```
vec <- rep(c("foo",rep(c('A','B'),2),"bar",rep(c("C","D"),2)),2)
idx <- vec %in% c("foo", "bar")
vec[cumsum(idx) %% 2 == 1 & !idx]
# [1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B"
```