# Get data from between two cell values of a dataframe R

Tags: r

related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775441/extract-data-between-rows-r) how is it possible from the following dataframe:

```
a <- rep(c("foo","ABC","DEF","bar","EFG","XYZ"),2)
df <- data.frame(a)

> df
      a
 1  foo
 2  ABC
 3  DEF
 4  bar
 5  EFG
 6  XYZ
 7  foo
 8  ABC
 9  DEF
 10 bar
 11 EFG
 12 XYZ
```

to extract the rows that are between 'foo' and 'bar' to get ?

```
> df
   a.1
2  ABC
3  DEF
8  ABC
9  DEF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
# find valid rows
idx <- apply(matrix(grep("^(foo|bar)$", df$a), 2) + c(1, -1), 2, Reduce, f = seq)
# extract subset of data
df[as.vector(unlist(idx)), , drop = FALSE]
#     a
# 2 ABC
# 3 DEF
# 8 ABC
# 9 DEF
```

Comment: idx <- matrix(grep("^(foo|bar)$", df$a), 2) + c(1, -1) seems to be enough for the job. Is there a particular reason why you added apply...?

Comment: @DJJ For this particular problem your code is sufficient. If you have more than two rows between `foo`and `bar`, it will miss some rows.

Comment: For the case you mentionned, it seems that the dataframe doesn't accept the list. What do you think of f[melt(idx)$value,,drop=F]?

Comment: @DJJ See the update. Now, it should work for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using `fun1` in the link provided:

```
 df1 <- data.frame(a.1=fun1(df$a, "foo", "bar"))
 df1
 #a.1
 #1 ABC
 #2 DEF
 #3 ABC
 #4 DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df[(match("foo", df$a)+1):(match("bar", df$a)-1), ]
[1] ABC DEF
Levels: ABC bar DEF EFG foo XYZ
```