# Regex to extract all text from a specified pattern till end of string in r

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to extract all the text from the word "Conclusion" till end of text using stringr

```
#example data: 

cc= structure(list(text = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Forest gardening, a forest-based food production system, is the world's oldest form of gardening.[1] Forest gardens originated in prehistoric times along jungle-clad river banks and in the wet foothills of monsoon regions. In the gradual process of families improving their immediate environment, useful tree and vine species were identified, protected and improved while undesirable species were eliminated. Eventually foreign species were also selected and incorporated into the gardens.[2]\n\nAfter the emergence of the first civilizations, wealthy individuals began to create gardens for aesthetic purposes. Ancient Egyptian tomb paintings from the New Kingdom (around 1500 BC) provide some of the earliest physical evidence of ornamental horticulture and landscape design; they depict lotus ponds surrounded by symmetrical rows of acacias and palms. A notable example of ancient ornamental gardens were the Hanging Gardens of Babylon—one of the Seven Wonders of the Ancient World —while ancient Rome had dozens of gardens.\n\nWealthy ancient Egyptians used gardens for providing shade. Egyptians associated trees and gardens with gods, believing that their deities were pleased by gardens. Gardens in ancient Egypt were often surrounded by walls with trees planted in rows. Among the most popular species planted were date palms, sycamores, fir trees, nut trees, and willows. These gardens were a sign of higher socioeconomic status. In addition, wealthy ancient Egyptians grew vineyards, as wine was a sign of the higher social classes. Roses, poppies, daisies and irises could all also be found in the gardens of the Egyptians.\n\nAssyria was also renowned for its beautiful gardens. These tended to be wide and large, some of them used for hunting game—rather like a game reserve today—and others as leisure gardens. Cypresses and palms were some of the most frequently planted types of trees.\n\nGardens were also available in Kush. In Musawwarat es-Sufra, the Great Enclosure dated to the 3rd century BC included splendid gardens. [3]\n\n Conclusion: Ancient Roman gardens were laid out with hedges and vines and contained a wide variety of flowers—acanthus, cornflowers, crocus, cyclamen, hyacinth, iris, ivy, lavender, lilies, myrtle, narcissus, poppy, rosemary and violets[4]—as well as statues and sculptures. Flower beds were popular in the courtyards of rich Romans.", 
"The Middle Ages represent a period of decline in gardens for aesthetic purposes. After the fall of Rome, gardening was done for the purpose of growing medicinal herbs and/or decorating church altars. Monasteries carried on a tradition of garden design and intense horticultural techniques during the medieval period in Europe. Generally, monastic garden types consisted of kitchen gardens, infirmary gardens, cemetery orchards, cloister garths and vineyards. Individual monasteries might also have had a \"green court\", a plot of grass and trees where horses could graze, as well as a cellarer's garden or private gardens for obedientiaries, monks who held specific posts within the monastery.\n\nIslamic gardens were built after the model of Persian gardens and they were usually enclosed by walls and divided in four by watercourses. Commonly, the centre of the garden would have a reflecting pool or pavilion. Specific to the Islamic gardens are the mosaics and glazed tiles used to decorate the rills and fountains that were built in these gardens.\n\nBy the late 13th century, rich Europeans began to grow gardens for leisure and for medicinal herbs and vegetables.[4] They surrounded the gardens by walls to protect them from animals and to provide seclusion. During the next two centuries, Europeans started planting lawns and raising flowerbeds and trellises of roses. Fruit trees were common in these gardens and also in some, there were turf seats. At the same time, the gardens in the monasteries were a place to grow flowers and medicinal herbs but they were also a space where the monks could enjoy nature and relax.\n\nThe gardens in the 16th and 17th century were symmetric, proportioned and balanced with a more classical appearance. Most of these gardens were built around a central axis and they were divided into different parts by hedges. Commonly, gardens had flowerbeds laid out in squares and separated by gravel paths.\n\nGardens in Renaissance were adorned with sculptures, topiary and fountains. Conclusion \n In the 17th century, knot gardens became popular along with the hedge mazes. By this time, Europeans started planting new flowers such as tulips, marigolds and sunflowers."
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I am new to regex but I did some search and used this but it is not working

```
pattern = "(?<=Conclusion)\S+(?:\s+\S+)$"

stringr::str_extract(cc$text, pattern)
```

the expected output is:

```
Ancient Roman gardens were laid out with hedges and vines and contained a wide variety of flowers—acanthus, cornflowers, crocus, cyclamen, hyacinth, iris, ivy, lavender, lilies, myrtle, narcissus, poppy, rosemary and violets[4]—as well as statues and sculptures. Flower beds were popular in the courtyards of rich Romans.

In the 17th century, knot gardens became popular along with the hedge mazes. By this time, Europeans started planting new flowers such as tulips, marigolds and sunflowers.
```

Any guidance?

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the pattern to match 'Conclusion' followed by ':' and a space or 'Conclusion' followed by space and next line and match all the characters after that (`.*`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(cc$text, "(?<=Conclusion: ).*|(?<=Conclusion \n ).*")
```

-output

```
#[1] "Ancient Roman gardens were laid out with hedges and vines and contained a wide variety of flowers—acanthus, cornflowers, crocus, cyclamen, hyacinth, iris, ivy, lavender, lilies, myrtle, narcissus, poppy, rosemary and violets[4]—as well as statues and sculptures. Flower beds were popular in the courtyards of rich Romans."
#[2] "In the 17th century, knot gardens became popular along with the hedge mazes. By this time, Europeans started planting new flowers such as tulips, marigolds and sunflowers."
```

---

Or use `trimws` after extracting

```
trimws(str_extract(cc$text, "(?<=Conclusion)\\s*.*"),
        whitespace = "\\s*[:\n]\\s*")
```

Comment: thank you. do I have to specify what comes after conclusion? is there a way to just use the word "Conclusion" regardless of what comes next? thanks again.

Comment: @Bahi8482 with regex lookbehind, it won't allow for one or more.  You may need to specify a fixed number of characters

Answer (score 1):

You can remove everything till `'Conclusion'` part in the string. Using base R this can be done as :

```
sub('.*Conclusion\\s*[:\n]\\s*', '', cc$text)

#[1] "Ancient Roman gardens were laid out with hedges and vines and contained a wide variety of flowers—acanthus, cornflowers, crocus, cyclamen, hyacinth, iris, ivy, lavender, lilies, myrtle, narcissus, poppy, rosemary and violets[4]—as well as statues and sculptures. Flower beds were popular in the courtyards of rich Romans."
#[2] "In the 17th century, knot gardens became popular along with the hedge mazes. By this time, Europeans started planting new flowers such as tulips, marigolds and sunflowers."
```

Comment: thank you. do you know if base r is faster than stringr or vice versa?

Comment: I haven't tested it but this post might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24846611/microbenchmarking-base-r-and-three-packages-on-string-pattern-substitution