# Matching exact words with sentences and forming a data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to match a list of words with a list of sentences and form a data frame with the matched words(coma separated) in one column and the corresponding sentences in another column. I want the words to be exactly match with the words in the sentence For eg:

Sample sentences and words:

```
sentences <- c("This is crap","You are awesome","A great app",
               "My advice would be to improve the look and feel of the app")
words <- c("crap","awesome","great","vice","advice","awe","prove","improve")
```

Expected Result:

```
sentences                                                     words
This is crap                                                 "crap"  
You are awesome                                              "awesome"
A great app                                                  "great" 
My advice would be to improve the look and feel of the app   "advice","improve"
```

I have thousands of sentences(28k) like this to be matched with thousands of words(65k). I follow the below approach to acheive this but the problem is i am unable to get the exact word match.

```
df <- data.frame(sentences) ; 
df$words <- sapply(sentences, function(x) toString(words[stri_detect_fixed(x, words)]));
```

I followed different approaches but nothing seems to be faster than this. But I could'nt use this approach as this does not match the exact word, instead matches the string containing the word. Can someone suggest me a solution that matches the exact words at the same time does not lose much performance?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr` package,

```
library(stringi)
data.frame(sentences = sentences, 
           words = sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(sentences, paste(words, collapse = '|')), paste, collapse = ','), 
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#                                                   sentences          words
#1                                               This is crap           crap
#2                                            You are awesome        awesome
#3                                                A great app          great
#4 My advice would be to improve the look and feel of the app advice,improve
```

Comment: This approach takes a lot of time (4 minutes) where as stri_detect_fixed used to take only 28 seconds

Comment: I ran the tests on the sample data and got 0.074 seconds for `str_extract_all` but got 0.0009 seconds for `stri_detect_fixed`. I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25467159/2361644). Here they have suggested to use stri_extract_all_regex, but i don't know how to use this to get my desired result. Could you help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think @Sotos answers the question well. But I'd like to add another way of representing it which I think might be more helpful for further analysis.

```
sentences <- c("This is crap","You are awesome","A great app",
                   "My advice would be to improve the look and feel of the app")
words <- c("crap","awesome","great","vice","advice","awe","prove","improve")

library(stringr)
mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(words, function(x) str_count(sentences, x)))
dimnames(mat) <- list(words,c())
data.frame(mat)
```

Output :

```
        X1 X2 X3 X4
crap     1  0  0  0
awesome  0  1  0  0
great    0  0  1  0
vice     0  0  0  1
advice   0  0  0  1
awe      0  1  0  0
prove    0  0  0  1
improve  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a slight adjustment to the neat approach of prateek1592 as it has the flaw of returning a match for the string "awe" in the second sentence, while the second sentence only contains that pattern but not that particular string. Changing the input of the str_count() from x to paste0("\b", x, "\b"), we get:

```
sentences <- c("This is crap","You are awesome","A great app",
               "My advice would be to improve the look and feel of the app")
words <- c("crap","awesome","great","vice","advice","awe","prove","improve")

library(stringr)
mat <- do.call(rbind,lapply(words, function(x) str_count(sentences, paste0("\\b", x, "\\b"))))
dimnames(mat) <- list(words,c())
data.frame(mat)
```

Output:

```
        X1 X2 X3 X4
crap     1  0  0  0
awesome  0  1  0  0
great    0  0  1  0
vice     0  0  0  0
advice   0  0  0  1
awe      0  0  0  0
prove    0  0  0  0
improve  0  0  0  1
```